# Systemically vs systematically

Tags: word-choice

From a colleague's email,

> "Given that the expected business process is not working and has been causing a lot of issues across different systems, it is evident that we need to enforce the process systematically."

Systemically or Systematically or better way to rewrite the sentence?

Comment: Which dictionaries did you consult before asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be *'the business process'*  which probably has not been properly organised jet and,  as a consequence,   needs to be enforced  in a [systematic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Systematic) way, that is with method, orderly.

> - having, showing, or involving a system, method, or plan: systematic efforts.

I think the *systems* the mail refers to are the different *'business environments'*  which are negatively affected by the unsystematic process approach adopted so far.

I think that the sentence is correct and clear.

Answer (score 2):

Systemic = being part of or emanating from a "system", be it an organism, body, organisation, structure.

Systematic = having an organised or methodical way.

For example,

> We are experiencing a systemic failure of in our electricity supply. It appears that the electricity grid system is failing due to systemic sabotage. Fortunately, the systemic sabotage was not done with a systematic attack, but by people who are amateurish.

**Dictionary**:

> [systematic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/systematic) (sɪstɪˈmætɪk)
>   adj
>
> 1. characterized by the use of order and planning; methodical: a systematic administrator.
> 2. comprising or resembling a system: systematic theology.
> 3. (Biology) Also: systematical biology of or relating to the taxonomic classification of organisms
>
> systemˈatically adv
>
> [systemic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/systemic) (sɪˈstɛmɪk; -ˈstiː- )
>   adj
>
> 1. another word for systematic
> 2. (Physiology) physiol (of a poison, disease, etc) affecting the entire body
> 3. (Agriculture) (of a pesticide, fungicide, etc) spreading through all the parts of a plant and making it toxic to pests or parasites without destroying it
>
> n
>
> 1. (Agriculture) a systemic pesticide, fungicide, etc
>
> sysˈtemically adv
>
> *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*

Comment: This doesn't actually say which word would be better to use.

Comment: I can't advise you because you did not tell us whether you would enforce the process using a system and treating the processes as members of a system, or by being systematic/methodical. Modify your question, and tell us which way did you intend.

Comment: Good point. You should ask the OP to clarify though, not me. :)

Comment: Didn't realise you weren't.